# What game elements can raise the caster level of a fixed-caster-level supernatural ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class, polymorph, caster-level

The prestige class **thrall to Juiblex** gains the [supernatural ability](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#special-abilities) **polymorph self** that says, "An 8th-level thrall of Juiblex’s form is more amorphous than ever. It can change its appearance and form at will, as the *polymorph self* spell cast by an 8th-level caster" (*Book of Vile Darkness* 70). (The DM is updating *polymorph self* to [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) to bring the thrall in line with the *3.5* revision.)

Absent that caster level, this supernatural ability's caster level would be the thrall's Hit Dice, but, because the ability's caster level *is* otherwise noted, the ability's caster level is fixed at 8… seemingly forevermore.

Before I recommend a new player takes on this character as a PC, I want to confirm: Are there any game elements that can raise this—or, more generally, *any*—supernatural ability's fixed caster level? Or is this something the DM needn't worry about?

---

***Note:*** For raising the fixed caster level of a spell-like ability, see answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48473/8610). By the way, yes, Mold is a warforged thrall to Juiblex who's reformed and now uses his unlimited ooze-summoning and form-changing abilities to fight crime. The Saturday morning cartoon almost writes itself.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The Orange Ioun Stone gives what looks to be an entirely untyped +1 to caster level.  You could easily houserule that things like that don't work for this case, but I think that under base rules it does.

The Adept Spirit spell (Magic of Incarnum, Clr2/Sorc3/Wiz3) is a buff that offers a short-duration insight bonus to caster level.

If you could somehow make Thrall of Jubilex count as a spellcasting class, then the Practiced Spellcaster feat could be argued to give you +4 for it, but I don't believe that's possible.

There may be other sources as well.  I believe they'd mostly be temporary, but, regardless, there *are* at least a few effects that give generic bonuses to caster level out there.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Paragon Creature: "If the base creature has spell-like abilities, it gains +15 to its caster level to use those abilities".  Thanks for the catch.  Have modified accordingly.

Comment: @HeyICanChan went back and re-read the class.  Don't know how I missed it.  Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: Even if thrall of Jubilex counted as a spellcasting class, Practiced Spellcaster (probably) wouldn’t hit the Su ability, since that wouldn’t be part of the spellcasting.

Comment: @KRyan It just says "your caster level for the class increases".  It does not specify that it's spellcasting-specific.  Saying that it doesn't apply is a reasonable assertion to make, if you're the DM, but it's not specified in the rules.  The polymorph caster level is a cater level, and it's associated with the class.

Comment: @KRyan still, I can see how it would be at least open to interpretation.  Have adjusted accordingly.